# How do I get the class name in a mixin?

Tags: typescript, mixins

How do I get the name of the class that is using a mixin instead of the name of the mixin class itself inside of a function defined within a mixin class?

To try help clarify, here is my code:

```
// this function is from TypeScript mixin documentation
function applyMixins(derivedCtor: any, baseCtors: any[]) {
  baseCtors.forEach(baseCtor => {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach(name => {
      derivedCtor.prototype[name] = baseCtor.prototype[name];
    });
  });
}

class ClassName {
  public getClassName(): string {
    var funcNameRegex = /function (.{1,})\(/;
    var results = (funcNameRegex).exec(this.constructor.toString());
    var className = (results && results.length > 1) ? results[1] : '';
    return className;
  }
}

class ExampleFoo implements ClassName {
  getClassName: () => string;
}

applyMixins(ExampleFoo, [ClassName]);
```

When I instantiate ExampleFoo and call getClassName it prints out "ClassName" but I need it to print out "ExampleFoo":

`console.log(new ExampleFoo().getClassName()) // => prints "ClassName"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to not copy the constructor. Replace the function `applyMixins` with:

```
function applyMixins(derivedCtor: any, baseCtors: any[]) {
  baseCtors.forEach(baseCtor => {
    Object.getOwnPropertyNames(baseCtor.prototype).forEach(name => {
      if (name !== 'constructor')
        derivedCtor.prototype[name] = baseCtor.prototype[name];
    });
  });
}
```